# How do I get checkstyle to fail when there is no blank line between javadoc and @param

Tags: java, javadoc, checkstyle

For instance, I have the code below. I want checkstyle to complain because there is no blank line between my top level javadoc comment and my @ clauses.

```
/**
 * This line or the next line should fail checkstyle.
 * @param param is essential
 * @throws Exception is thrown when something bad happens
 */
```

Checkstyle should not complain when the javadoc is changed to look like:

```
/**
 * This line or the next line should no longer fail.
 * 
 * @param param is essential
 * @throws Exception is thrown when something bad happens
 */
```

I tried using @Mureinik 's suggestion and it does not complain about my lack of blank line between the first paragraph and the @-clauses. I verified that eclipse has recognized that I enabled JavadocParagraph in the screenshot below.

```
<module name="JavadocParagraph"/>
```

[image]

Comment: Where it says you must have a blank line?

Comment: "... and one blank line before the at-clauses block if it is present."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is [now available](https://checkstyle.sourceforge.io/apidocs/com/puppycrawl/tools/checkstyle/checks/javadoc/RequireEmptyLineBeforeBlockTagGroupCheck.html) with

```
<module name="RequireEmptyLineBeforeBlockTagGroup"/>
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`JavadocParagraph`](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/config_javadoc.html#JavadocParagraph) check should ensure that. Just add the following to your checkstyle configuration:

```
<module name="JavadocParagraph"/>
```

Comment: I applied your suggestion but I'm still not getting that javadoc warning.

Comment: I read through the docs and see "There is one blank line between each of two paragraphs and one blank line before the at-clauses block if it is present." not sure why javadoc is not complaining about my example.

Comment: This is currently a bug in checkstyle, see https://github.com/checkstyle/checkstyle/issues/6192 .

Comment: I've selected this answer since it's technically correct by following the documentation. Unfortunately, it doesn't work yet. I filed that bug against the checkstyle project on github.

Comment: I've switched the answer to RequireEmptyLineBeforeBlockTagGroup since that works.